# Why i cannot get the width and height of my webpart in C#?

Tags: server

I want to get the width and height in px of my webpart, however, it shows an error as shown below.

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Width.get'

Do anyone know what how can i fix it?

my code:

```
string width= Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Width;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to first get an instance of the particular webpart, you are trying to find the dimensions of.

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("SiteURL")
{
  using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPWebPartCollection webparts = spWeb.GetWebPartCollection("WebPageURL", Storage.Shared);

    for (int k = 0; k < webparts.Count; k++)
    {
      //get reference to webpart
      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart wp = webparts[k];

      //check webpart Title to find webpart whose value is to be changed
      if (wp.Title == "MyWebpartTitle")
      {
        //get width and height property values of the webpart object
        string strWpWidth = wp.Width;
        string strWpHeight = wp.Height;
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

[MSDN WebPart.Height property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.height.aspx)

[MSDN WebPart.Width property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.width.aspx)